# Calculate $\sup\{ |2x+y| : |x|^p+|y|^p=1\} $

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

I need to find $\sup \{ |2x+y| : |x|^p+|y|^p=1\}$ for $1\leq p < \infty$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{C} $. My idea is to bound the supremum upward by $2|x| +|y|$ and then maximizing $2x+y$ over the positive reals with $x^p+y^p=1$ and then checking that I can find $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ so that |2x+y| match this maximal value. But when i try to differentiate with regard to $x$ and setting equal to $0$ i get $(1-x^p)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}x^{p-1}=2$ and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Do u know Lagrange multipliers? That gives you the relation between $x,y$ which by rotation you can assume positive

Comment: No I don't know anything about Lagrange multipliers unfortunately, can you expand on how to use it?

Comment: set $f(x,y,\lambda) = 2x+y+(x^p+y^p-1)$, find the partial derivatives and set them all equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using Holder's inequality. I will take $1<p<\infty$ since the case $p=1$ is easy. If $q=\frac p {p-1}$ then  $|2x+y| \leq (|x|^{p}+|y|^{p})^{1/p}(2^{q}+1)^{1/q}=(2^{q}+1)^{1/q}$ and the value $(2^{q}+1)^{1/q}$ is attained when $(x^{p},y^{p})=c(2^{q},1^{q})$ where $c$ is chosen so that $|x|^{p}+|y|^{p}=1$, namely $c=\frac 1  {2^{q}+1}$. Hence the answer is $(2^{q}+1)^{1/q}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how the value is attained. If $|2c|^p+|c|^p=1$ then $c=(2^p+1)^{-\frac{1}{p}}$. And then why would $5c$ be equal to $(2^q+1)^{\frac{1}{q}}$? This in fact is false for $p=3$, so perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Caspar Sorry, there was a mistake and I have corrected my answer.